# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "yyyy-mm-dd"

Tags: java, date, gson, date-parsing

Upon trying to parse a JSON that contained two string properties of the form "yyyy-mm-dd", I get the following error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-08-07"
```

I use `ReimbursementRequest rr = gson.fromJson(req.getReader(), ReimbursementRequest.class);` to parse them, where `gson` is a public static instance set to `new Gson()`. Will I need to define `gson` another way, and if so, how?

Comment: May we see the code for `ReimbursementRequest`, assuming it can easily fit?

Comment: It contains a class that contains the `Date`s.

Comment: Even though you have already answered your own question, I think you should still include an MCVE in this question so that future readers with a similar problem will benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the vanilla `new Gson()`, use `new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').create()`; // and it worked like a charm